# After Pandas groupby.value_counts() how can I filter on the result?

Tags: python, pandas

im still quite new to pandas..
I managed to receive a Series with the following groupby clause:

```
data.groupby("salary_percentile").early_quitter.value_counts(normalize = True)
Out:
    salary_percentile  early_quitter
[17000, 25000]     0                0.744526
                   1                0.255474
(25000, 30000]     0                0.751880
                   1                0.248120
(30000, 38000]     0                0.701799
                   1                0.298201
(38000, 46000]     0                0.772118
                   1                0.227882
(46000, 53000]     0                0.742015
                   1                0.257985
(53000, 57000]     0                0.720339
                   1                0.279661
(57000, 61000]     0                0.745763
                   1                0.254237
(61000, 64000]     0                0.688144
                   1                0.311856
```

I do only need the salary_percentile and the respective second value of percentages (where the early quitter columns is 1) - how would I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs(1, level=1)
print (df)

salary_percentile
[17000, 25000]    0.255474
(25000,30000]     0.248120
(30000,38000]     0.298201
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: And if I now would like to pairplot - having the salary buckets on a x-axis and the percentage on the y-axis - would I need to transform the Series into a Dataframe? or can I plot index vs var?

Comment: I think no, you need only `df.xs(1, level=1).plot()`